# Concurrent Instances - Data / Design problem

Tags: c#, software-design, avalonia

I'm trying to come up with a design for an application (C#/Avalonia) which will allow creating views for data coming from multiple sources. The overall idea is to link the sources and present outcome using various visualization components.

There are multiple sources of data:

- Database 1
- Database 2/3/4
- SOAP

Database 1 is going to be used to store everything related to the application itself (users, permissions and so on).

Databases 2-4+ are only data feeds.

SOAP - this is where I struggle, not quite sure how to handle. There could be 10-50 concurrent instances of the application running, and each one of them could request the same data update from SOAP (provider restrictions would make it impossible).

What I was thinking was to take the following approach:

1. Request initial data from SOAP
2. Cache the data in database 1 with a timestamp
3. Define a delay between the requests
4. Once a user requests a data update from SOAP, check if we should return cached or fresh data based on timestamp and delay value.

This approach leads to an issue where the user terminates the application in the middle of requesting new data.

- User 1 requests new data, marks database to ensure no future requests are processed
- User 2 requests new data - nothing happens at this stage, wait and query again
- User 1 terminates - no new data for any users

Is the approach completely wrong and trying to handle it using Client only would be a suicide?

Comment: How stable is the SOAP-Data and is it mission critical to always have the latest data?

Comment: The data from SOAP is critical for most of the views, some of it might need to be updated every minute while some won't be as critical.